# How can I add a scrollbar? I tried adding overflow:auto to body and it didn't work

Tags: html, scroll, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

Simple question for most of you I'm sure. I added a scrollbar using the overflow:auto on a text box within my page. Tried the same thing with the body but it doesn't work.

If I change the size of my browser window, no scrollbar appears and I loose half the content.
[www.mcgregor-beauty.co.uk](http://mcgregor-beauty.co.uk)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your html element is styled to `overflow: hidden` which is preventing the scrollbars from appearing and just hiding excess content.

To fix it either remove this declaration from your html or add an override for the html element to set `overflow: auto` as you've tried for body.